# JS mouseover/mouseout blinking but not staying

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

Here's a little code I have problem with:

```
$(".setEtiquette").mouseover(function(){
    var rightFrame = $(this).attr("name");
    $('#'+rightFrame).fadeIn();
}).mouseout(function(){
    var rightFrame = $(this).attr("name");
    $('#'+rightFrame).fadeOut();
});
```

When on the  setEtiquette, the rightFrame is blinking but that's not what we want it here, we want it stay and leave when moving to another etiquette...

Do you have anything that would help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem was that the rightFrame should leave when the mouse went out. Removing the mouseout wouldnt work since it leaves the rightFrame visible. Using mouseenter, mouseleave just do the trick without triggering over and over the rightFrame ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mouseover() fires when the pointer moves into the children elements as well, while mouseenter() fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.
You may want to try mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout, if the blinking is due to existing children of the elements you are binding to.

Comment: It might be worth adding (for non-jQuery users) that onmouseenter / onmouseleave are non-standard Microsoft events. However, jQuery simulates this for cross browser support.